# why do we modelize an electronic double layer with a classic capacitor?

Tags: electrochemistry

in an electronic double layer, there is a voltage drop between the metal and the solution but in the litterature, scientists always modelize EDL with a classic capacitor. My question is why ? because for me, the two electrodes have not the same potential (+/-), it is assymetric ...